# Combobox Dinamico con php

Tags: php, html, html5

Buscando la solucion a esto llego aqui.

Estoy programando un pequeño combobox dinamico con php, al grano.

Tengo mi **combobox 1** que seria meses y el **combobox 2** que seria dias, la idea es que al seleccionar *Febrero* en el **combobox 1**, automaticamente el **combobox 2** solo me imprima 28 dias y no 31.

```html
<select name="Meses del año">
 <option value="0">Selecione un mes del año</option>

 <?php 
  for ($i=0; $i < sizeof($meses); $i++) { 
  ?>
  <option value="<?php echo $meses[i]; ?>">
   <?php 
    echo $meses[$i];
    ?>
  </option>
  <?php 
 }
   ?>

 </select>

 <select name="Dias del mes">
  <option value="0">Seleccione un dia del mes</option>
  <?php 
   for ($x=0; $x <count($dia) ; $x++) { 
   ?>
   <option value="<?php echo $dia[$x];?>">
    <?php 
     echo $dia[$x];
     ?>
   </option>
   <?php 
   }
    ?>
 </select>
```

Es una pequeña porcion del codigo en cuestion, lo que esta anterior son el array de meses y dias.

Comment: Te recomiendo usar JQuery ya tiene un plugin de calendario que se llama Datapicker, pero si aun sigues prefiriendo hacerlo como lo tienes lo que deberias hacer es meter javascript y con el evento onchange en tu combobox cuando se cambie se ejecute una función que te devuelva los elementos del combobox2 y asi puedas mandar los dias que correspondan segun el mes seleccionado.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por responder M. Gress, pero efectivamente me hubiese gustado una solucion netamente en php. Pero de igual manera ojala haya un guru de la vida que haya solucionado algo igual a mi problema

Comment: De nada, pero lo que te comentan abajo es la verdad, no hay forma de hacerlo son con php ya que requieres minimo javascript para ejecutar alguna función cuando algun evento se dispare, suerte. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es imposible que hagas eso con PHP dinámico, al momento de hacer la petición el PHP se procesa en el servidor y en la respuesta del lado del navegador ya solo tendrás HTML, por lo cual ya al momento de "escuchar" el cambio en el combobox al mes de Febrero, no pasará nada (Ni con los meses de 30 días).

(Puedes hacer una nueva llamada al servidor al seleccionar el mes `localhost:8080/?mes=febrero` y llenar de manera dinámica el arreglo `$dia` y refrescar la página)

Lo que podrías hacer sería escribir un script en Javascript para modificar de manera dinámica los campos, o su librería mas popular jQuery, o mediante una llamada AJAX, volver a llamar a PHP para realizar el cambio.

También puedes usar librerías como Datapicker para quitarte de problemas con Scripts y HTML.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por tu comentario Azteca, la verdad que lo explicaste muy bien. Y ademas tiene toda la razon que se me paso eso, php trabaja por detras e iba ser imposible. Tu comentario es la luz por asi decirlo.